# Getting a return for mysql_query

Tags: php, mysqli

Following a tutorial, how would I convert this to mysqli? I found the error that it was mysql_query that wasn't supported anymore, so I already switched it to mysqli_query, but now I'm stumped on where to move on from there. How would I return that function?

```
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; }

function user_id_from_username($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id'); }
```

Future thanks.

Comment: Please read the fantastic manual at http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php as it will tell you what you need to do.

Comment: Bad coding: **NEVER** chain DB queries. `mysql_result(mysql_query())` will fail at some point, and since you blindly assume nothing can ever go wrong, you'll never find out until some OTHER code that calls this function fails.

Answer (score 0):

Sky is wrong with his assupmtions

You need to do a few things

1. The basic syntax for a mysqli_query is `mysqli_query($link,$query)`.  This means that you need to change your query statements to `mysqli_query($link,"YOUR QUERY TEXT HERE")`.
2. In order for the above to work you need to change your database connection variable.  You used to have `$link=mysql_connect("host","username","password")`.  You need to change that to `$link=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database")`
3. Then you need to change all `mysql_result` to `mysqli_result`

All of what I have written above is publicly availible on the PHP.net resource
http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php

If you need to know anything about mysqli check there first